# Jasmine Unit Test For Angular Datatable

Tags: angularjs, unit-testing, karma-jasmine

I am using Angular Datatable in my current project & want to unit test that using Karma-Jasmine. But my test is failing with DTOptionsBuilder.fromFnPromise().withColVisOption is not a function.

I have mocked DTOptionsBuilder as below in my Jasmine unit test

```
 $provide.service('DTOptionsBuilder', function(){
               this.fromFnPromise = jasmine.createSpy('fromFnPromise').andCallFake(function(){
                   //a fake implementation
                   return {};
               });
           });
```

Is there anything I am missing?